# Time-critical sampling of a source observable with RxJava?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I'd like to be able to sample emissions from a source observable at consistent intervals, regardless of CPU-intensive work further down the chain. This code demonstrates the problem: it samples reliably at 500ms intervals with `doSlowOperation()` commented out, and then starts to lag and give inconsistent results when it is uncommented.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `test sample operator lag`() {
        Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .sample(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .timestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map {
                doSlowOperation()
                it
            }
            .take(4)
            .toList()
            .subscribe { item ->
                val itemsWithNormalisedTimestamps = item.map {
                    val timeSinceStartMs = (it.time() - item.first().time())
                    "${timeSinceStartMs}ms"
                }
                println("Got items: $itemsWithNormalisedTimestamps")
            }

        Thread.sleep(20000)
    }

    private fun doSlowOperation() {
        val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
        for (i in 0..10000000) list.add(i)
    }
```

Output with `doSlowOperation()` commented:

```
Got items: [0ms, 500ms, 1001ms, 1499ms]
```

Output with `doSlowOperation()` uncommented:

```
Got items: [0ms, 1610ms, 2093ms, 3157ms]
```

Note that although it would be good if the slow operation were performed more-or-less in real-time, it's not so time-sensitive as the sampling itself. I.e. it doesn't matter if a backlog of sample emissions accumulate into some kind of queue to be processed when they can, so long as the sampling continues to occur at precise intervals.

I've tried making the source observable hot (with `publish()` and `connect()`) and also tried moving the slow operation onto another scheduler with `observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` without any luck.

Comment: Perhaps put your "slow operation" into a scheduled executor task that pushes a single value into the stream each time?

Comment: Try `observeOn` with a custom `Schedulers.from` right after `sample` to decouple to processing of the sampled item from the sampling thread.